# Controlling an application running on ServerDevice via. controllerApp running on another device

Tags: android, file, bluetooth, controls, transfer

I have 2 application : ServerApp and ControllerApp. Each of theses application run on different android devices. ServerApp has an area where images are displayed sequentially (in an ImageView). ControllerApp contains two buttons and a ImageView. two buttons are previous and next buttons which shall navigate the screen of the ServerApp using bluetooth. I need to show the current image being shown on the ServerApp on the ImageView portion of the ControllerApp.

I think I would need some socket programming. I am new to android. I tried using INTENT.SEND and then starting a new activity but still not sure how to implement the above. Please help me implementing this by giving some ideas. Thanks in advance

Krishna